# onselect show/hide new select

Tags: jquery, onselect

Because I have a db like this

```
id - id_parent - name
1  - 0         - root
2  - 1         - child_1
3  - 1         - child_2
4  - 3         - child_31
5  - 3         - child_32
6  - 2         - child_21
```

I have to create a select that "onselect" show a new select with child

Then first select from db was

```
<select>
 <option>empty</option>
 <option>root</option>
</select>
```

On root select, new select on bottom was

```
<select>
 <option>child_1</option>
 <option>child_2</option>
<select>
```

I'm trying to do that with jquery...

Comment: post jsfiddle here

Answer (score 0):

see this code i solve your problem , i think that will help you to do this work

https://plnkr.co/edit/ckEIglujjD9OIOqeT6l5?p=preview

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

  <select id="parent">
    <option value="0">empty</option>
    <option value="1">root</option>
  </select>

  <select id="child">

  </select>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var info = [{
          id: 1,
          parent: 0,
          name: 'root'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          parent: 1,
          name: 'child_1'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          parent: 1,
          name: 'child_2'
        }, {
          id: 4,
          parent: 3,
          name: 'child_31'
        }, {
          id: 5,
          parent: 3,
          name: 'child_32'
        }, {
          id: 6,
          parent: 2,
          name: 'child_21'
        }


      ];


      $("#parent").on('click', function() {

        var nowValue = $(this).val();
        $("#child").html("");
        $.each(info, function(index, value) {
          if (value.parent == nowValue) {

            var option = $('<option/>');
            option.attr({
              'value': value.id
            }).text(value.name);
            $('#child').append(option);
          }
        });

      });


    });
  </script>
```

Comment: mmm, ok but this is a tree of 2 level... I need "infinite" level... If I select child_1, new select with child_21 must show...